# Target first element of DIV using CSS

Tags: css, html

I have a WYSIWYG editor inside of a table that is placed within a div, as such...

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <li>
        <table>My WYSIWYG</table>
    </li>
</table>
```

Inside my WYSIWYG there are more tables however I only want to target the first table, I understand I could assign a class to the table but thats not what I want.

I've tried using the following only it doesn't seem to work...

```
.mydiv li + table {width:100%;}
```

Comment: Have you tried this: .mydiv li table:first-child

Comment: An `li` as the immediate descendant of a `div` is bad practice, `li` are only meant for lists (dl, ul, ol).

Comment: Which browser(s) does this need to work in? Some do not support the selector you are using

Comment: @lofto - Not `dl`. But in HTML5, `li` can also be the child of `menu`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need `.mydiv li table:first-child`.

[More information](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-child-pseudo).

`:first-child` works in IE7+ and all modern browsers.

[An example.](http://jsfiddle.net/74eSh/)

---

`.mydiv li + table` isn't working for you because that matches something like this:

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <li></li>
    <table>My WYSIWYG</table>
</div>
```

---

Also note that there are few things wrong with your HTML:

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <li>
        <table>My WYSIWYG</table>
    </li>
</table>
```

- `</table>` at the end should be `</div>`.
- The `div` should be a `ul`, because `li` is not a valid child of `div`.

I've fixed these things in the demo above.

Answer (score 3):

Give this a go:

```
ul li:first-child table
{
    background: red;
}
```

The key here is `:first-child`. As @Warface notes, this isn't compatible with some browsers (pretty much only IE6), but all modern browsers support `>` just fine. [See this.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

[Demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/TzUL3/). Please note I've changed the markup to what is (a) correct and (b) what I think it should be.

Comment: Great but not all browsers compatible since it's CSS3

Comment: Actually, it's a CSS 2.1 selector. According to http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html, all browsers except IE6 support `>` properly.

Comment: Looking at this again, `li:first-child table` probably is the correct selector (as opposed to `li table:first-child`). It depends where the extra tables are, it's not entirely clear.

Comment: It's not. I took the markup in the OP and made it correct, so some assumptions have changed the selector.

Answer (score 2):

Amazing what a quick google or stackoverflow search will do for you!

```
.mydiv li table:first-of-type { width:100% }
```

Comment: @Liam: You should use `:first-child` instead if it works for you. `:first-of-type` doesn't work in IE7/8, which are [unfortunately still used](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201007-201107). It works in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`:first-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html) pseudo element

But be wary of browser support.